# Effect of surprise dividends on options

Tags: options

The ETF in question is VDC

It pays about $2.5 a year in dividends, but the payout dates are very erratic

If I were to go long VDC with options, what would be the best way of doing this to avoid dividend risk and to keep transaction fees minimal?

Shorting a deep in the money put would be a bad idea if the dividend is announced because it would cause the put to gain value in anticipation the dividend, assuming the ex-dividend date is before the option expires.

Buying a deep in the money call would probably work, but I would have to be very careful to exercise it before the ex-dividend date .

Dividends can be quite problematic

Any other ideas?